# Proper way to debug your own framework project from main app project in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, debugging, frameworks, xcode8, sourcekit

I have read about two possibilities for that:

- To build the framework as debug, to add it to main app project, and run the main project also as debug. Breakpoints should allow you to inspect the frameworks code stepping into it.
- To add somehow the framework project itself to the main app project

I tried first one and it is not working for me. I get an `Couldn't Generate Swift Representation` when trying to step into framework's code. If this option should still work in `Xcode 8` and `Xcode 8.1`, what settings should I check?

If the best/only option now is the second one, how should I properly set that?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?